# Error 0xfffffc03 when decoding multiple videos

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-mediacodec

I'm facing a strange error with MediaCodec, it happens when I have a background service using the MediaCoded to process a video and start the playback of another video in an activity.

**Stack trace of the error:**

```
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffc03
at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:577
at net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer.MediaCodecVideoDecoder.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoDecoder.java:47)
at net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer.MediaCodecDecoder.reinitCodec(MediaCodecDecoder.java:163)
at net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer.MediaCodecVideoDecoder.<init>(MediaCodecVideoDecoder.java:42)
at net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:276)
at net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer.MediaPlayer$2.run(MediaPlayer.java:347)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**MediaCodec call that generates the error:**

```
@Override
protected void configureCodec(MediaCodec codec, MediaFormat format) {
    codec.configure(format, mVideoSurface, null, 0);
}
```

***Obs.:*** This problem only happens sporadically on my Samsung Galaxy S6, while in my One Plus X it works flawlessly.

## Update

I was not able to fix this problem so my solution was to change the architecture of my app in such a way that multiple decodings don't happen at once. Turns out that the decoding problem happens due to an actual hardware limitation, so the decoding of multiple videos in specific formats could trigger such issues in some devices.

However, if anyone finds a solution to this problem it would be useful anyway.

Comment: Is the surface you're decoding into still available - sure that you haven't gotten a `surfaceDestroyed` callback before?

Comment: I don't believe that is the case for two reasons. First, my code works on other phones and second, both the video playback and video processing work well alone.